# Django inconsistency of uwsgi and dev servers

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I faced strange problem. With the same Django project, site behaviour is different on development server and uwsgi server. Uwsgi and devsrv point to the same settings.py file.

The issue here is that one particular app (commented out in settings file) is present in uwsgi server, but absent in development server. This app should be turned off on both servers. Files are the same, because it is the same tree. I have no idea where to seek for bug.

It seems like uwsgi do not notice any changes in settings file, and stores previous version somewhere. I do restart uwsgi every time I make changes. I also tried rebooting machine.

Comment: Do you reload uwsgi after change ?

Comment: Ofc I did. I even tried rebooting machine. Nothing helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was Celery module, and definition in celery.py file in my project dir. In celery.py there is line:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
```

I have two sites running on the same project but settings files are different for each other. I defined in the line above, settings file for first site but tried to run second. That is why settings have been overriden.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure that everything is same, try clearing `pyc` files.

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -delete # from your code directory
```

If I had a penny for everytime `pyc` files messed up things...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but problem was related to celery included in my Django project.